# Populate BootstrapTable x-editable select box based on another column

Tags: javascript, jquery, bootstrap-table

I have a BootstrapTable select box. I know you can use a function to populate the values in the select box. I'd like that function to change which array it provides based on the value of a second column (called `Text_example`).

So in my example, if `Text_example` for that row is `1`, the select box should have the following data: `[{1:1}]`. if `Text_example` for that row is `2`, the select box should have the following data: `[{2:2}]`

I think my problem is that I don't know how to pass just the row's data to the function `get_values` as my method seems not to be working.

Full Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/goxe6ehg/

```
var data = [{"Text_example": 1},{"Text_example": 2}];

function get_values(data) {
    if (data['Text_Example'] === 1) {
    return [{1:1}];
  }
  else {
    return [{2: 2}]
  }

}

$('#table').bootstrapTable({
  columns: [
   {
      field: 'Select_example',
      title: 'Select_example',
      editable: {
        type: 'select',
        source:  get_values($('#table').bootstrapTable('getData'))
      }
    },
    {
      field: 'Text_example',
      title: 'Text_example'
    }
  ],
  data: data
});
```

EDIT: I over-simplified my example. Rather than having a static field for `text_example` I need it to be a select box, where the value for `select_example` changes based on what the user has selected in `text_example`.

Updated JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/4wwv18Lq/4/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the oninit handler on the bootstraptable library.And add the editables by iterating through the data object.

```
var data = [{"Text_example": 1},{"Text_example": 2}];

$('#table').on('editable-init.bs.table', function(e){
    var $els =  $('#table').find('.editable');
     $els.each(function(index,value){
            $(this).editable('option', 'source', data[index])
     });

});
$('#table').bootstrapTable({
  columns: [
   {
      field: 'Select_example',
      title: 'Select_example',
      editable: {
        type: 'select'
      }
    },
    {
      field: 'Text_example',
      title: 'Text_example'
    }
  ],
  data: data
});
```

JSfiddle link
http://jsfiddle.net/km10z2xe/

Comment: This is great and did answer my question, but I stupidly over-simplified my model. I need the select box to be based on another select box, which the user can change. This doesn't work for this because it sets the values on initialization.  I've added an edit to my question. Would you mind taking a look? http://jsfiddle.net/4wwv18Lq/4/

Comment: yeah sure i will take a look at it

Comment: @user2242044 I have made the update according to the edit.

Comment: Thank you that is awesome. It won't let me give the bounty out for 24 hours, but I'll come back tomorrow and give it to you.

Comment: Thank you.. Cool.